# Create sorted array from a list of domain names [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dns, subdomain

I'm trying to turn a list of domains into a nested array, based on their subdomains. This seems trivial at first but my little brain is struggling.

Input:

```
example.com
www.example.com
email.example.com
1.email.example.com
example.net
```

Expected output.

```
$array = array(
    "com" => array(
        "example",
        "example" => array("www","email"=> "1")),
    "net" => "example",
);
```

I can get somewhat close with the following code:

```
$a = 'a.google.com';
$b = 'b.google.com';
$c = 'c.google.com';
$a1 = '1.a.google.com';
$a2 = '5.2.a.google.com';
$a3 = '3.a.google.com';
$d = [$a,$b,$c,$a1,$a2,$a3];
$result = [];

foreach ($d as $domain){
    
    $fragments = array_reverse( explode( '.', $domain ));
    
    for ($x = 0; $x <= count($fragments)-1; $x++) {         
        if (!is_array($result[$x])){ $result[$x] = [];}
        array_push($result[$x], $fragments[$x]);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Although that doesn't nest the arrays and i can't see how i can access the correct arrays to push the data to without some sort of variable array construction. halp! :P

Answer (score 0):

Here I check to see if the exploded array is greater than 2 elements and if so take the last one for the value to be added to the result:

```
foreach($d as $domain) {
    $path  = array_reverse(explode('.', $domain));
    
    if(count($path) > 2) {
        $value = array_pop($path);
    } else {
        $value = false;
    }
    $temp =& $result;
    
    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    if($value) {
        $temp[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although the formatting of this seems to break when you have domains with mutiple subdomains, for example if $a = '1.22.a.google.com'; then the result array (in JSON format for readability) is: {"com":{"google":{"a":{"22":["1"],"23":"1","2":["5"],"24":"3"},"0":"b","1":"c"}}}.